Getting Error Exception calling application: [Errno 5] Input/output error sometimes
my sample.proto file
syntax = "proto3";
package protofile;
import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";
import "google/protobuf/struct.proto";
option go_package = "./contracts/grpc";

message EventCallbackRequest {
  string event_sid = 1;
  string event_type = 2;
  string event_name = 3;
  google.protobuf.Timestamp event_timestamp = 4;
  string action_sid = 5;
  string action_custom_parameter = 6;
  google.protobuf.Struct event_data = 7;
  google.protobuf.Struct data = 8;
}

message EventCallbackResponse {
  string message = 1;
  bool success = 2;
}

service EventCallbackTriggerService {
  rpc TriggerCallbackEvent(EventCallbackRequest) returns (EventCallbackResponse) {}
}

sample_server.py
import grpc
from concurrent import futures
import sample_pb2
import sample_pb2_grpc

from google.protobuf.json_format import MessageToDict

class SampleEventHandler(sample_pb2_grpc.EventCallbackTriggerServiceServicer):
    def TriggerCallbackEvent(self, request, context):
        print("hiiiiiiii----------------")
        data = MessageToDict(request)
        print(f"data is {data}")

        return sample_pb2.EventCallbackResponse(message="Event received", success=True)

def serve():
    server = grpc.server(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1))
    sample_pb2_grpc.add_EventCallbackTriggerServiceServicer_to_server(SampleEventHandler(), server)

    server.add_insecure_port('[::]:50051')
    print("gRPC server running on port 50051...")
    server.start()
    server.wait_for_termination()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    serve()

sample_client.py
import grpc
from google.protobuf import struct_pb2, timestamp_pb2
import sample_pb2_grpc as pb2_grpc
import sample_pb2 as pb2
from datetime import datetime


def run():
    target2 = 'grpc-test.squadstack.com:443/protofile.EventCallbackTriggerService/TriggerCallbackEvent'

    credentials = grpc.ssl_channel_credentials()

    # Establish a secure channel with Nginx (SSL and HTTP/2 for gRPC)
    with grpc.secure_channel(target2, credentials) as channel:
        # Create a stub (client) to make requests to the gRPC service
        stub = pb2_grpc.EventCallbackTriggerServiceStub(channel)

        # Prepare timestamp
        event_timestamp = timestamp_pb2.Timestamp()
        event_timestamp.FromDatetime(datetime.now())

        # Prepare sample Struct data
        event_data = struct_pb2.Struct()
        event_data["key1"] = "value1"
        event_data["key2"] = "value2"

        # Create a request with necessary event details
        request = pb2.EventCallbackRequest(
            event_sid="2K8DQQuKWiXhXdfpMnXJYKV0TdB",
            event_type="leg_lifecycle_event",
            event_name="leg_incoming",
            event_timestamp=event_timestamp,
            action_sid="action-123",
            action_custom_parameter="custom-param",
            event_data=event_data,
            data={
                "account_sid": "abcd60",
                "caller_id": "XXXX",
                "contact_uri": "YYYY",
                "date_created": "2023-01-10T10:41:39.607712401Z",
                "date_updated": "2023-01-10T10:41:39.607712401Z",
                "dc_code": "101",
                "direction": "inbound",
                "exophone": "YYYY",
                "leg_sid": "2K8DQQr2eoPW6HXJej7VesxsTUy00000",
                "network_type": "pstn",
                "nso_code": "9988fd96-ce41-11ed-9a09-0242ac110003",
                "start_time": "2023-01-10T10:41:39.039873482Z",
                "state": "ringing",
                "time_limit": 14400
            }
        )

        # Send request to the gRPC server via Nginx and receive response
        try:
            response = stub.TriggerCallbackEvent(request)
            print(f"Server response: {response.message}, Success: {response.success}")
        except grpc.RpcError as e:
            print(f"gRPC call failed: {e}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()

I have setup nginx config to listen on port 50051. nginx is returning 200.
Sample response of nginx
{"level": "info","ts": "2024-09-18T08:18:14+00:00","message": "handled request POST /protofile.EventCallbackTriggerService/TriggerCallbackEvent","request": {"id": "50bb0cfe3ba03c733693c656ad331579","remote_ip": "192.168.1.95","remote_port": "18562","protocol": "HTTP/2.0","method": "POST","scheme": "https","host": "grpc-test.squadstack.com","uri": "/protofile.EventCallbackTriggerService/TriggerCallbackEvent","headers": {"user-agent": "grpc-python/1.66.1 grpc-c/43.0.0 (osx; chttp2)","accept": "","accept-encoding": "","referer": "","x-forwarded-for": "49.249.150.126","x-forwarded-proto": "https"}},"connection": {"bytes_read": 907,"bytes_sent": 124},"timing": {"duration_msecs": 0.001,"upstream_connect_time": "0.000","upstream_header_time": "0.000","upstream_response_time": "0.000"},"response": {"status": 200,"headers": {"content_length": "0","content_type": "application/grpc"}},"upstream": {"address": "127.0.0.1:50051","status": "200","response_length": "0","cache_status": ""},"ssl": {"protocol": "TLSv1.3","cipher": "TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256","session_reused": ".","server_name": "","client_verify": "NONE","client_s_dn": ""},"gzip_ratio": ""}

Whenever I run sample_client.py 8 out of 10 I get the following error
gRPC call failed: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.UNKNOWN
    details = "Exception calling application: [Errno 5] Input/output error"
    debug_error_string = "UNKNOWN:Error received from peer  {grpc_message:"Exception calling application: [Errno 5] Input/output error", grpc_status:2, created_time:"2024-09-18T14:41:17.38932+05:30"}"
>
On 

success, I receive
Server response: Event received, Success: True

I tried searching for Input/Output error but I did not find anything useful that could help me solving the problem. There is enough disk space in my server.
We are using ubuntu server to run sample_server.py. I am running sample_client on my local to the server hosted on 'grpc-test.squadstack.com:443/protofile.EventCallbackTriggerService/TriggerCallbackEvent'.
Requirements
grpcio==1.66.1
grpcio-tools==1.66.1

Python - 3.9 in both client and server
Can someone please help.
I checked nginx configuration, it is returning 200. Getting this Input/Output error is completely random and I am not able to understand the reason behind this.
Ideally this should return success every time if server port is up and running on 50051 port.

Your question omits the NGINX config. Are you able to run the client against the server directly without issue? I'm unable to repro your issue. Your client and server work for me (using Tailscale to provide a TLS proxy to the server) and using gRPCurl.

This is working fine now. I checked there were some orphan workers running. I checked via sudo ss -tuln | grep :50051 command. Once I killed using sudo fuser -k 50051/tcp and started sample_server.py then it worked!
